# What alloys and metals can fantasy dwarves refine/create?

Tags: science-based, medieval, metals

What metals are dwarves capable of refining and producing?

I'm working on a setting where the players have a *lot* of meta knowledge (Computers and nukes in a pre-industrial world anyone?¹) and need to know almost exactly what metals/alloys dwarves have access to normally in a medieval setting to avoid giving them too much/too little when the game starts.

This can assume a earthlike geography and metal concentrations, as I can adjust from there myself.

The technology level of the dwarves, in my world, is around that of the early industrial age. They have access to steam engines, and can manipulate metal using simple driven machines. The ores they have access to is really going to be highly varied, as i'm waving my hand at moderate speed to give them access to most ores. (Less uranium this time, to avoid them destroying BOTH continents, and causing me a lot of pain. Gods are radioactive enough as it is.)

Other races in the world are far behind the dwarves in this regard, giving them a monopoly over military weaponry, at least in the forts that have access to it.

¹ For reference, they already turned the other continent into a nuclear wasteland. They're starting over from scratch, as they successfully killed themselves in the process.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding. Are you asking for what A dwarf can produce? Or what a dwarf has access to? In both cases, this is a world you are building, so you can choose what knowledge they retain and what metals they have access to. I'm inclined to say all of them.

Comment: @Shadowzee I am aware. I was hoping for a good idea of what alloys and metals are feasible for the average fantasy dwarf. I.E. aluminium is a obvious "no", as they cannot refine the ore it occurs in, only Native Aluminium, so the chances of it gaining a common use is very low.

Comment: @moonheart08 So you are basically asking, what metals/alloys can be made at a forge?

Comment: @Shadowzee for medieval dwarves, yes.

Comment: This entirely depends on what technological level you want them to have, do they have access to blast furnaces, chemical refining, gas smelting,  electricity? How much has their technology recovered?

Comment: Blast furnaces at most, @John. Like I said, medieval levels. The research the *players* had has been mostly wiped out from the map, due to them nuking themselves into oblivion, and them not really sharing :P

Comment: Fantasy dwarves are sometimes depicted as unrivalled masters of almost anything to do with metal and/or any ores. So, I don't think we can say what "a fantasy dwarf" can do. Maybe they can make alloys we struggle with today. That's certainly not beyond fantasy. Maybe they are about as good as a decent human blacksmith.

Comment: Could you please add the extra information in comments making the question more specific to the question itself (by editing it in) ?  Please don't expect members to scan comments for that kind of information.

Comment: What kind of tech do dwarved have? What materials are available to them?

Comment: @Renan Finding out what materials are available to them is the point of this question..?

Comment: @moonheart08 you got it the oyher way around then. I'm asking because, for instance, you can't make steel without iron. Asking what materials are available to them, then, boils down to asking which ores they have access to, and that id all up to you as the author.

Comment: @Renan It's stated in my question that you can assume earth-like ore concentrations.

Comment: I'll give you an example. Do your dwarves know how to make a curved blade by using a harder alloy on the edged side and a more flexible alloy on the other? Do they know how to build ceramic forges? Do they know how to reforge a piece of metal more than 150 times without breaking it? All of this goes into making blades of the past, from katanas to damascus steel swords.

Comment: You focus too much on the players of your scenario -- to me that indicates the DM has lost control of his game. But anyway: am voting to close until you can clarify the many issues brought up in comments.

Comment: @elemtilas The insanity the players cause is kinda the norm on Bay12Forums. There isn't a game there where the players arn't abusing every inch of the game's design. Anyways, will do, gonna clarify. (I was hoping to make the question more generic so it helps more people than just me)

Answer (score 5):

- Bronze
- Steel
- Gold
- Silver
- Brass
- Lead
- Zinc
- Mercury
- Copper
- Tin
- Iron
- Billon
- Bismuth
- Nickel
- Electrum
- Antimony
- Platinum

Comment: Platinum?  Antimony?  I think also (and maybe relevant for this world) that you could use alchemical methods to refine uranium metal from ore.

Comment: @Willk Can confirm the uranium thing has very much been done. How else would they make a nuclear wasteland? (Well, they did propose a bomb powered by *souls*, but that was shut down for being way too gamy)

Comment: While I mostly agree with the list a breif description of how you determined what was on it would make this answer vastly better. Note refining of nickel  and bismuth don't occur until after the intention of the steam engine.

Comment: @John Dwarves could be assumed to have such an engine, at least in my universe. For others, it's unlikely.

Comment: @moonheart08 Refine uranium from minerals is one thing, but enriching uranium  to make a bomb is a whole different beast. Even with today's technology is extremely complicated, requiring complex technology only a few countries possess - such as industrial centrifuge machines. I'm ignoring the fact that you need an atomic theory to make a bomb since you say meta-knowledge is allowed. Iran is far more advanced that late medieval age and yet they can't made a bomb without Siemens equipment.

Comment: @Rekesoft This was done by metagaming players. They knew, and they did it. They wasted a *lot* of magic in the process to perform the otherwise nigh impossible tasks.

Comment: note some other metals will occur in minute amounts, there area few  artifacts made from aluminum as native aluminum does occur very very rarely, rare enough to be more valuable than gold by volume, Napoleon famously had a set of aluminum cutlery for his most honored guests, less favored guests had to make due with only gold cutlery.  I always assumed this is what mithril was, aluminum alloy, super light and when alloyed with iron nearly as strong.

Answer (score 3):

So - standard medieval metals could include;

- Copper
- Tin
- Brass
- Bronze
- Lead
- Iron/Steel*
- Gold/Silver/Platinum

*The exact grade of steel/iron and what they can make out of it depends on the Dwarves exact tech level, resources and economics. Interesting read [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42610/what-metallurgy-advancement-allowed-the-transition-from-mail-hauberk-to-plate-ar) over at the History StackExchange

As you mentioned Aluminium requires modern process in order to refine, so only small nuggets of native aluminium would have been available. Titanium is even worse, as it wasn't even discovered till fairly late, and only really started being refined and used in the 20th century.

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to give it a fantastic spin, go with something like:

- Star Metal
- Mithril (commonly associated with dwarves)
- Thunder Iron
- Blue Steel

For extra world building points, name the metal after a dwarf community. ie. Baldwin Hills -> Ballard Iron.

To base it on something believable find a known metal and its modern uses and allow those dwarves to have figured it out - while the rest of the world is using an inferior metal for the job; i.e the dwarves have figured out bronze, while everyone else is just using copper. Steel to iron, titanium to steel.

Don't forget that the metal alone is only half the issue, how it is refined, forged, and cooled can have a drastic effect on the metals strength. Compare Japanese Katanna to a knights long sword. Both are essentially forged from very similar metals. The process of refining and folding the katana metal however makes them superior in terms of function.

Comment: For other people, this is great advice. In my case, the world is being "rebuilt", and I can't retcon everything. Otherwise I would probably do this. Some specific metals from the real world that weren't discovered until the 20th century have leaked over already, for example, Invar.

Comment: A japanese katana and an european longsword start from very different materials, the japanese had to use so much folding to even out all the impurities in steel because they only had inferior ores, downside of living on an island. Folding is only good if you have a poor quality starting material. Historic katana are markedly inferior to european sword steel, it is brittle  brittle and weak, that is part of the reason their sword techniques focus so much on protecting the blade, they just can't take the same punishment as even middle quality european swords of the time.

Comment: @John you know that, swordsmiths might know it, but the rest of us think that katana are wonder weapons...  :)

Comment: Fair enough I'll double check my sources on Katanna technology. That however still underscores the point that how metal is processed and worked has ramifications for its properties in the resulting product.